# Use :after selective for inline style setting

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have style sheet like this below,

```css
h3 {
  position: relative;
  background: #dfefff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #dfefff;
  border: dashed 2px white;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  color: #454545;
}

h3:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -7px;
  top: -7px;
  border-width: 0 0 15px 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff #fff #a8d4ff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<h3>Title</h3>
```

However in my web regulation, I can't use  tag

So I have to use like

`<h3 style ="position: relative;background: #dfefff;~~">`

How can I use `h3:after` in this style??

Comment: You cannot define, or change, pseudo element styles *inline*. The reason is that you can only apply *rules*  in the style attribute, and not use any *selectors*. Because the pseudo elements have no *tag*, there's nothing to put the appropriate `style` attribute on.

Comment: I think it should have been `h3::after`. I don't know what your "regulation" is, but I think changing your css should work.

Comment: can you use class name or id instead of tag as a selector?

Comment: I hate to be one of *those* people, but if your only option is *inline* then use [inline javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin). Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add `pseudo` operator `inline Style`, because `Pseudo` operators are only workable in CSS `classes` and `Ids`

and you are taking about adding `pseudo` operator with `style` attribute, which is not possible, 
 ***For more information visit this article***. this will help you 
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/

Comment: *because Pseudo operators are only workable in CSS classes and Ids* **Double wrong.** 1. There's no such thing as *pseudo **operators***. 2. pseudo **selectors** can be applied to **any** (non-pseudo) selector, not just class and id selectors.

Comment: I am just giving the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way possible to use `pseudo` in inline CSS. if you want to use the `pseudo` then you have to use it `internal CSS` or `External CSS`.

Answer (score -1):

You can recreate the same differently without the need of pseudo element.

<sup>Only the small shadow is missing</sup>

```html
<h3 style="background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,#fff 49%,#a8d4ff 50%) 0 0/15px 15px border-box,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) top/100% 2px,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) bottom/100% 2px,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) left/2px 100%,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) right/2px 100%,
    #dfefff;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border:5px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  color: #454545;">Title</h3>
```